# "Asked" box background bleeds into related questions

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

In the bottom-right corner of a question, the background of the "asked by" box bleeds into the list of related questions:

[image]

(By the way, I'm using Google Chrome 13 when reporting these bugs.)

Comment: do you have a url for this?

Comment: @Jin Sorry forgot to mention, it happens on all question pages for me.

Comment: I can't repro this. Are you using a userscript by any chance?

Comment: @Jin Neither can I after a reboot. Sorry about the time wasting. I've checked the others I reported and can still repro them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't reproduce this in Chrome 13 (latest ver as of writing) on Windows 7....